# Объясните, пожалуйста, что здесь происходит

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

```
const getNumber = x => (f = x => x) => f(x);
const setOperator = f => y => x => f(x, y);

const five = getNumber(5);
const plus = setOperator((x, y) => x+y);
const minus = setOperator((x, y) => x-y);

console.log(five(plus(five()))); //10
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics, https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#znacheniya-po-umolchaniyu

Comment: Но вообще тут происходит развлечение с функциями высшего порядка и прочей <s>чертовщиной</s> функциональщиной.

Comment: В математике вроде бы это называется композиция функций, в js тоже если не ошибаюсь, но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @Elmir https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function. Композиция это когда результат вычисления одной функции передаётся другой, например `sin(ln(x))` — композиция синуса и логарифма. В примере выше композиция только в последней строке.

Comment: `setOperator` это каррирование https://learn.javascript.ru/currying-partials а в общем это всё https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

`getNumber` - функция, в первый аргумент предполагается число (аргумент `x`), сама функция возвращает другую функцию, которая и возвращает аргумент, написанный вами в аргументах функции.

Пример:

```js
const getNumber = x => (f = x => x) => f(x);

const функция_возвращающая_число_42 = getNumber(42)

const число_42 = функция_возвращающая_число_42()

console.log(число_42)
```

`setOperator` - функция, принимающая в аргумент другую функцию (аргумент `f`), сама функция `setOperator` возвращает ещё одну функцию в первый аргумент, который вписывается число `y`. А сама эта функция (та которая принимает число `y`), возвращает ещё одну анонимную функцию, в которую в свою очередь вписывается число `x`, уже при вызове этой функции (принимающей число `x`), вызывается та самая функция `f` которую мы написали в аргументы `setOperator` в самом начале.

Пример:

```js
const setOperator = f => y => x => f(x, y);

const функция_принимающая_y = setOperator((x, y) => x + y)
const функция_принимающая_x = функция_принимающая_y(2)
const результат_сложения_x_и_y = функция_принимающая_x(2)

console.log(результат_сложения_x_и_y)
```

Если, разбирать код на части, то получится вот такая вот каша:

```js
const получить_функцию_возвращающую_первый_аргумент /* getNumber */ = x => (f = x => x) => f(x);

const получить_функцию_возвращающую_анон_функцию_принимающую_y /* setOperator */ = f => y => x => f(x, y);

const функция_возвращающая_число_5 /* five */ = получить_функцию_возвращающую_первый_аргумент(5);

const функция_принимающая_y /* plus */ = получить_функцию_возвращающую_анон_функцию_принимающую_y((x, y) => x + y);

const функция_принимающая_x_у_которой_y_равен_5 /* plus(five()) */ = функция_принимающая_y(функция_возвращающая_число_5())

const результат_сложения_x_и_y /* five(plus(five())) */ = функция_принимающая_x_у_которой_y_равен_5(функция_возвращающая_число_5())

console.log(результат_сложения_x_и_y)
```

P.S. код такой, что сам чёрт ногу сломит.

Comment: `getNumber` это вводящее в заблуждение название. По хорошему она должна называться `примени_функцию_к_значению(x)`. Например `const apply_f_to_36 = getNumber(36); apply_f_to_36(Math.sqrt) /* → 6 */;  apply_f_to_36(String) /* → '36' */`